# Create react app - Is it possible to inject a specific stylesheet last?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

Am using `import "./App.css"` in `index.js`

Is there anyway to make sure this style is injected last, amongst the other injected styles?

To clarify, I'd specified `import "./App.css"` last in my app. However, [MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) is able to inject itself last instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to inject something after MUI styles. MUI uses [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) which is a **CSS-in-js** implementation. CSS-in-JS libraries load CSS **on demand** using `style` tags. That is why it ends up adding styles very last.

You can hack your way out of it by dynamically and lazily injecting your `link` tag. But even then MUI may end up adding styles as and when different components get loaded by your application views.

Comment: Guess its not worth the effort then. Interesting to know emotion injects styles dynamically, thanks for the info.

Comment: @hackerl33t It is straightforward. Internally, it maintains a **hash bucket** for the styles. The key is basically a a `stringified` version of your style object. Since it is a hash, during each re-render the stringified version of your key is constant and it can quickly check if the style is already added to the DOM. When the style is changed dynamically (using conditions or etc.), it becomes a new key and thus gets added to the DOM. Of course, there is a theoretical penalty but performance is more than good enough for most of the user interfaces.